# Why does this code fail to nullify all keybindings in a keymap?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

Long story short, there's a little library I like but I don't like any of the default keybindings.  E.g. it's a global minor mode and binds a function to `C-c C-s`, but that shadows `org-schedule` in my org and org-agenda buffers.

I want to keep the little library but get rid of all the bindings in the little library keymap.

In an early attempt to do this, I tried the following (after confirming that `little-library-mode-map` is where the bindings live):

```
(with-eval-after-load "little-library-mode"
  (setq little-library-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap)))
```

The code "succeeds" (`C-h v little-library-mode-map RET` shows that it's just `(keymap)` now) but all the little library keybindings still "work" (`C-c C-s` still does the little library function, including in org and org-agenda buffers).

I've found another way to solve my issue, but I'm really curious why this approach fails.  Emacs' keybindings still seem like black magic to me.

Comment: You'll need to destructively modify the data structure the minor mode uses, like `(setcdr little-library-mode-map nil)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three important things in this story:

- the minor mode keymap
- its name
- the sparse keymap you create

Basically what you did is make the name point at the sparse keymap instead of the original, but it's too late: the minor mode uses the original.

Comment: Ah, got it. When you put it that way it makes perfect sense. Do you know how Emacs / the minor mode finds the original keymap? What data structure does it look in?

Comment: @purple_arrows the original keymap is in `minor-mode-map-alist`.

Answer (score 2):

At some point when activating `little-library-mode` the keymap stored in the variable `little-library-mode-map` gets added to `minor-mode-map-alist`:

```
(push (cons 'little-library-mode little-library-mode-map) minor-mode-map-alist)
```

Emacs uses this alist to lookup minor-mode bindings. When you bind the variable `little-library-mode-map` to a new value afterwards this has no effect on the keymap `minor-mode-map-alist` points to. As noted in the comment by @wasamasa one way to get rid of all bindings in this keymap is to mutate the keymap directly:

```
 (setcdr little-library-mode-map nil)
```

Another way is to reset the keymap before loading the library:

```
(setq little-library-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap))
(with-eval-after-load "little-library-mode" 
    ...more-setup-code)
```

If the minor-mode is well behaved, this will avoid instantiating its bindings, too.